How to vertically align RichElementText and RichElementImage elements inside RichText in cocos2d-x?
I have RichText in cocos2d-x with a RichElementText and a RichElementImage. The size of image is larger than text and since text is bottom aligned text appear as subscript of image. I want to center align the text vertically inside RichText.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
